# Copying the directory tree and file contents of only specific folders

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch-file, cmd.exe, robocopy

I'm trying to archive a large amount of files from only subfolders with a specific name. 
I'd also like to maintain the original folder structure in order to keep it simple for my team to access the archived files.

So far, I've found how to do this for specific filenames using robocopy, but I can't seem to get this to work for specific folders.

```
robocopy "c:\folder1[wildcard?]\obsolete" "c:\folder2\" \E
```

example:

```
c:\folder1\client1\obsolete\
c:\folder1\client1\obsolete\ (files & folders I'd like to copy)
c:\folder1\client1\project1\
c:\folder1\client1\file.txt
c:\folder1\client2\project1\
c:\folder1\client2\project1\obsolete\ (files & folders I'd like to copy)
c:\folder1\client2\project2\
c:\folder1\client3\obsolete\
c:\folder1\client3\obsolete\ (files & folders I'd like to copy)
```

result:

```
c:\folder2\client1\obsolete\
c:\folder2\client1\obsolete\ (files & folders)
c:\folder2\client2\project1\obsolete\
c:\folder2\client2\project1\obsolete\ (files & folders)
c:\folder2\client3\obsolete\
c:\folder2\client3\obsolete\ (files & folders)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion



REM **************************************************

SET source_dir=C:\folder1

SET target_dir=C:\folder2

SET wildcard=obsolete

REM **************************************************



FOR /D /R %%G IN ("%source_dir%") DO (
    SET "folder_name=%%G"
    ECHO !folder_name! | FINDSTR /R "%wildcard%" >nul && CALL :copy
)


ECHO. & ECHO. & ECHO. & ECHO. & ECHO. & ECHO Done^^!
PAUSE
EXIT


:copy    
SET target_folder_name=!folder_name:%source_dir%\=!

SET endbit=!target_folder_name:*%wildcard%=!
SET target_folder_name=!target_folder_name:%endbit%=!

SET endbit=!folder_name:*%wildcard%=!
SET folder_name=!folder_name:%endbit%=!

ROBOCOPY "!folder_name!" "%target_dir%\!target_folder_name!" /E
EXIT /B
```

The `wildcard` is case-sensitive, unless you add the `/I` option to `FINDSTR`:

`ECHO !folder_name! | FINDSTR /I /R "%wildcard%" >nul && CALL :copy`